# math.random de 2 char en java

Tags: java, random, math

una consulta quiero hacer un math.random que me genere la 'A' o la 'R' pero no se como hacerlo. si o si tiene que ser usando math.random solo lo eh utilizado con numeros hasta ahora

Comment: Hola, Recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste , revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo así: defines un array con los caracteres que quieres generar al azar, y luego usas un random entre 0 y 1 (el límite en el método nextInt() es exclusivo):

```
char[] chars = {'A', 'R'};
Random random = new Random();
int next = random.nextInt(2);
System.out.printf("Random letter: %s", chars[next]);
```

Comment: claro yo vi algo asi ya buscando , pero quiero usar el math.random por que la clase random no la vimos en clase y no dejan utilizar cosas que no vimos :/

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este código de ejemplo, en resumen lo que haces es generar un número aleatorio del 1 al 100, si el número es mayor o igual que 50 entonces tu carácter será una R, pero si no será una A.

De esta forma cada que generas la letra, la probabilidad de que sea A es del 50%, y la probabilidad de que sea A también es de 50%.

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i= 0; i < 20; i++) {
      System.out.println(randomChar());
    }
  }


  public static int randomInt() {
    return (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1 + 1) + 1);
  }

  public static char randomChar() {
    return randomInt() >= 50 ? 'R' : 'A';
  }
}
```

[Aquí](https://repl.it/repls/ColossalSympatheticEquipment#Main.java) puedes correr el ejemplo:

Answer (score 0):

El método `Math.random` genera un número real doble en el intervalo [0.0, 1.0), es decir, igual o mayor que 0.0 y menor que 1.0, como se indica en la [documentación de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()).

Lo que puedes hacer es separar ese intervalo en dos rangos: [0.0, 0.5) y [0.5, 1.0). Si el número aleatorio cae en uno de los rangos, devuelves una letra; si cae en el otro rango, devuelves la otra letra.

```
char letraAleatoria() {
    double aleatorio = Math.random();    // Se genera el aleatorio
    if (aleatorio < 0.5) return 'A';     // 50% de probabilidad de que esté en este intervalo
    else return 'R';                     // 50% de probabilidad de que esté en el otro intervalo
}
```

Si lo simplificas a una sola expresión con el operado ternario `?:` te queda:

```
char letraAleatoria() {
    return Math.random() < 0.5 ? 'A' : `B`;
}
```

Más información sobre el operador ternario [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) (en la sección *The Conditional Operators*).